# How do I allow users to download a GeoTiff on my web map

Tags: openlayers-2, ogc

I am hoping to get help with what I need to do in order to allow a user on my OpenLayers map to download a portion of a GeoTiff they are viewing through a WMS. The data is hosted through GeoServer. I would like the user to be able to simply click a button and download the bounds of the original file

I am not sure what steps I need to take in order to begin this process. I have worked a lot with serving geospatial data. But never in a way which allows the user to download the data. Any guide in the right direction would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i think you should use WCS instead of WMS for sharing raster datasets on the Web. AFAIK, wms dont have this capabilities for sharing tiff images.

From Wikipedia:

> Unlike OGC Web Map Service (WMS), which portrays spatial data to
>   return static maps (rendered as pictures by the server), the Web
>   Coverage Service provides available data together with their detailed
>   descriptions; defines a rich syntax for requests against these data;
>   and returns data with its original semantics (instead of pictures)
>   which may be interpreted, extrapolated, etc., and not just portrayed.
>
> Unlike OGC Web Feature Service (WFS), which returns discrete
>   geospatial features, the Web Coverage Service returns coverages
>   representing space/time-varying phenomena that relate a
>   spatio-temporal domain to a (possibly multidimensional) range of
>   properties. As such, WCS focuses on coverages as a specialized class
>   of features and, correspondingly, defines streamlined functionality.

and you can check out WCS info for geoserver [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wcs/reference.html).

> Benefits of WCS
>
> WCS provides a standard interface for how to request the raster source
>   of a geospatial image. While a WMS can return an image it is generally
>   only useful as an image.The results of a WCS can be used for complex modeling and analysis, as it often contains more information. It also allows more complex querying - clients can extract just the portion of the coverage that they need.
>
> WCS output formats
>
> Georeferenced formats:
>
> ```
>     GeoTiff - (format=geotiff)
>     GTopo30 - (format=gtopo30)
>     ArcGrid - (format=ArcGrid)
>     GZipped ArcGrid - (format=ArcGrid-GZIP)
> ```

i hope it helps you..

Comment: Thanks! That def is what I need. Haven't worked with WCS before - its just been one of those that I am used to skipping over.

Comment: Word of warning about WCS - not many people use it and support for it is lacking. When I used it a few years ago, even the "reference standard" had quite a few glaring bugs (hopefully since fixed). Its also massively processor intensive depending on what you're doing compared to WMS/WFS.